# javax.naming.InitialContext is a restricted class. Please see the Google App Engine developer's guide for more details

Tags: java

Whenever I tried to run my Google App Engine project(using JSF 2 and Apache MyFaces), got following error:

**java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.naming.InitialContext is a restricted class. Please see the Google  App Engine developer's guide for more details.**

Any solution?

Comment: What did the Google App Engine developer's guide say about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try what it suggests? You're probably looking for the [JRE class whitelist in the developer's guide](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/jrewhitelist.html), which *doesn't* list `javax.naming.InitialContext`. I.e. you can't use that class in GAE.